# (c++) calculation of intercepting an object that is orbiting around a center point

Tags: c++

I have been working on a simulation of a projectile launcher that fire a projectile to a target that is orbiting around center point. I do appreciate if someone would help explaining what is wrong with my calculation. (User input radii from center to the object, angle of center and the object, speed of the target, speed of the projectile)

This is part of my calculation function.

```
void::targetMove()
{double theta = 360;
theta = theta - angle;
PosX = (radius*cos(theta));
PosY = (radius*sin(theta));
angle = angle*timeStep;
return;}
```

This is part of my main.cpp

```
target tar;
projectile pro;
double spd, spd2, timeStep = 0, radius, ang;
launcher lau;
bool miss = true;
do
{
pro.distanceCal();
timeStep++;
tar.setTimeStep(timeStep);
cout<<"\n*TIME STEP "<<timeStep<<"*"<<endl<<"------------"<<endl;
tar.display();
if (abs((spd2*timeStep)/2 - pro.distanceCal()) <= 1)
{cout<<"\nThe projectile hits the target."<<endl<<endl;
miss = false;}
else
{ miss = true;}
while (miss);
```

This is my distance calculation function

```
double projectile::distanceCal()
{ distance = sqrt(pow(tar.getPosX()-tar.getCenterX(),2)+pow(tar.getPosY()-tar.getCenterY(),2));
return distance;}
```

My problem is that it looks like the of the orbiting target is not moving in circular motion. I kept getting weird numbers as my output for the new position of the target.

Thank you in advance for your kindness.

These are all functions that do all the calculation. The rest are just get/set functions.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and manual/Wolfram Alpha-powered computations to check your formulas? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It looks like your angles are in degrees. The library functions will want angles in radians though. Where is `angle` defined?

Comment: Oh I didn't change the angles from degree to radians. I will fix that and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: I have changed degrees to radius but it's still having weird output.